# After updating ssh, root login from only one IP does not work anymore

Tags: ssh

I've configured the ssh server in one of my PCs to allow root login from only one PC. This worked just fine, until I updated ssh (currently, the server is running Debian Jessie). Here is what my sshd_config looks like:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

############# To Allow Root Login ####################
Match Host pc01
    PermitRootLogin yes
```

Here is the result of doing ssh -v root@p00:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to pc00 [10.255.255.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 6a:be:7f:f8:3a:89:26:0b:08:16:6f:5a:ec:12:d7:bc
debug1: Host 'pc00' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/masteradmin/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masteradmin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Just to be clear, the update was done to the server and it worked just fine, before it.

I would like to configure the server to ONLY allow root access from pc01 (it's in the hosts file) and ONLY with key exchange.

What is wrong with my configuration?

UPDATE: Another clue, is that if I change the PermitRootLogin from no to yes, I can login just fine, however, it kind of defeats the purpose of the whole "allow root from only one IP" thing....

Comment: Did you allow the update process to install the default configuration file for your SSH daemon?

Comment: No I did not. And I'm thinking that might be the problem, actually. But I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The following construction has one issue:

```
PermitRootLogin no
...
Match Host pc01
  PermitRootLogin yes
```

It is described in the manual page for `ssh_config(5)`:

> **For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used.**

This means that `PermitRootLogin yes` will never get used. To avoid it, write the configuration the other way round:

```
Match Host pc01
  PermitRootLogin yes
Match all
  PermitRootLogin no
```

**Edit:** If the `hosname`-based `Match` blocks stopped working, it is probably related to `UseDNS` option, which could change the default with some of the updates. Change the `hostname` to the `IP` or adding `UseDNS yes` will solve the problem too.

Comment: This did not work. But it did help me figure out the problem. If I commented the PermitRootLogin at the beginning and added the lines recommended here it did not work. But commenting the Match all lines, I got it to work as well. This told me that there was a problem with the hosts file (which I checked and it was fine). So I replaced the pc01 with the actual IP. This worked even setting PermitRootLogin to no. So I'm not sure why, but this has worked. I'm not marking this answer as correct because I did something different to solve the problem.

Comment: If you would say that you updated RHEL/CentOS, I would tell you that there was change in default in `UseDNS` to `no` and therefore the `Match` did not get matched.

Comment: The client computer has CentOS, but the server has Debian. Where would I check this, configuration?

Comment: Try to add `UseDNS yes` into the `sshd_config` (before the match block).